# Comparing tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I'm extremely new to ML and DL and so I apologise if what I'm asking is basic. However, I am working on a project where I need to compare the values of two string tensors (or so I thought) for the purpose of creating a custom error metric. This is my code for the purpose at hand (it does not work and does not serve the required purpose):

```
def custom_error_finder(y_pred,y_actual):
    count = 0
    a_value=''
    print(y_actual)

    if (tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(y_pred, y_actual))):
        count=count
    else:
        count = count+1
    return count
```

However, when I execute `print (y_actual)`, it shows `Tensor("dense_4/Relu:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)` (the csv file has string components in it. I am sure since I collected and compiled the data myself).

So, my questions are:

1. Why is the tensor being recognised a float tensor with no rows?
2. How can I compare each element of the two tensors?

Comment: It isn't really possible for us to tell what is the problem without a more comprehensive example. Please try to extend your snippet to make a full reproducible example that we can try and see the error.

Comment: @jdehesa I dont mind posting the rest of the code but the rest of it is just me creating the model and calling the fit, and compile methods.

Comment: The thing is, `y_actual` is the value that the function is receiving. Without knowing where that value comes from, it's hard to tell what's going on. There is not much that can be concluded from the current code only.

Comment: `y_actual` is coming from the output of the dense layer. By default the layer outputs are `float32`. Also you have to remember that the graph of the model is created before the code is run so these linkages are already made. `None` doesn't mean no rows, it means the value is not specified and needs to be specified when the data is given. Example, `batch_size`

Comment: for the second part of your question you can use `tf.math.equal`. Documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/equal)

Comment: @learner in my code, y_actual is the true value that is already present in the csv file.

Comment: @learner, I tried using tf.math.equal but how do I get a full boolean value instead of an array of booleans?

Comment: you have the parameters interchanged, it should be `y_actual` followed by `y_pred`, therefore your `y_actual` is `float32`. And to get a single boolean value you can use `tf.reduce_all(tf.math.equal(a, b))` where `a` and `b` are the tensors for comparison